# Pandas dataframe howto

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following python dictionary with lists of dictionaries data structure:

```
data = [
 {'NAME': 'PROD',
  'HOSTNAME': 'BARNEY',
  'DC': 'NYC',
  'VERSION': 'v8.2.2.0',
  'POOL': ['A2000', 'F800', 'H500'],
  'NODE COUNT': [10, 5, 40],
  'TOTAL': [8725.2, 830.82, 3881.21],
  'USED': [3547.36, 381.24, 2116.89],
  'FREE': [5177.84, 449.57, 1764.32]},
 {'NAME': 'DR',
  'HOSTNAME': 'PLUTO',
  'DC': 'BOS',
  'VERSION': '9.1.0.15',
  'POOL': ['A2000'],
  'NODE COUNT': [42],
  'TOTAL': [14061.05],
  'USED': [6008.57],
  'FREE': [8052.49]}
]
```

When i pass to a Pandas dataframe it looks like this

```
   NAME HOSTNAME  ...                        USED                        FREE
0  PROD   BARNEY  ...  [3547.36, 381.24, 2116.89]  [5177.84, 449.57, 1764.32]
1    DR    PLUTO  ...                   [6008.57]                   [8052.49]

[2 rows x 9 columns]
```

How can I make this look like the excel table below using Pandas? Basically the rows of the first 4 columns need to how many pools are in the pool array.

[image]

Comment: Please provide valid objects that can be used in example code (the object you've provided is _not_ valid Python). You probably should look into [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html).

Comment: I updated the post to reflect the list of dicts

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data).explode(["POOL", "NODE COUNT", "TOTAL", "USED", "FREE"])
```

Result:

```py
   NAME HOSTNAME   DC   VERSION   POOL NODE COUNT     TOTAL     USED     FREE
0  PROD   BARNEY  NYC  v8.2.2.0  A2000         10    8725.2  3547.36  5177.84
0  PROD   BARNEY  NYC  v8.2.2.0   F800          5    830.82   381.24   449.57
0  PROD   BARNEY  NYC  v8.2.2.0   H500         40   3881.21  2116.89  1764.32
1    DR    PLUTO  BOS  9.1.0.15  A2000         42  14061.05  6008.57  8052.49
```